# update if the id based on difference in time

Tags: mysql

I have a table below

```
std_id intra_id number startime           
1        245     18970  20170101 10:30:31 
2        245     18970  20170101 10:40:00 
3        245     18970  20170101 10:50:12 
4        789      6586  20170101 12:34:45 
5        754     346456 20170101 10:23:45 
6        4332    234567 20170101 10:13:40 
7        4332    234567 20170101 10:26:46
```

joining table

```
 intra_id number endimeime
   245     18970  20170101 10:29:31
   789      6586  20170101 12:34:45
   754     346456 20170101 10:23:45
   4332    234567 20170101 10:12:30
```

Expected output:

```
std_id intra_id number startime            diff
    1   245   18970   2017-01-01 10:30:31   60
    2         18970   2017-01-01 10:40:00   629
    3         18970   2017-01-01 10:50:12   1241
    4   789   6586    2017-01-01 12:34:45   0
    5   754   346456  2017-01-01 10:23:45   0
    6   4332  234567  2017-01-01 10:13:40   70
    7         234567  2017-01-01 10:26:46   856
```

I have tried this by taking time difference between start-time from the i/p and end-time from joining table. but it is not updating according to my expected output.

so when my intra_id count>1 for the same number but different std_id then it has to have single intra_id for the number which has less diff-time

Comment: I don't understand how you arrived at the output?

Comment: I didn't yet, I have to achieve the expected output. I have to update the main table based on time difference

Comment: It is not clear how you arrived at your expected output using the data you provided.

Comment: `diff` field doesn't seem to express the actual time difference between `startime` and `endtime` fields. For example for `intra_id = 4332` `diff` should be equal to `70`, `856` instead of `60`, `90`.

Comment: updated the difference.

Comment: @Tim: I have only those fields , from that I have to archive the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT std_id, IF(grp = 1, intra_id, '') AS intra_id,
       number, startime, diff
FROM (       
   SELECT std_id, 
          intra_id,
          @grp := IF(intra_id = @id, @grp + 1,
                     IF(@id := intra_id, 1, 1)) AS grp,  
          number, startime, diff
   FROM (
      SELECT t1.std_id, t1.intra_id, t1.number, t1.startime,
             TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(t1.startime, t2.endtime)) AS diff
      FROM table1 AS t1
      JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.intra_id = t2.intra_id) AS t   
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @id := 0) AS v   
   ORDER BY t.intra_id, diff) AS x;
```

The query uses variables in order to achieve the `intra_id` 'not display' effect, though this is preferably handled by the presentation logic of your application.

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/YLLTJ5827)

Comment: Thanks for the Query. but i see still intra_id ahs value where std_id = 3.. it should also be null